# saving user input into an array and making sure it does not violate index

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on an assignment and editing a program.  I am asking the user to enter a their salesperson number, product number, and how much they sold.  I am trying to save the sales data as an array called `sales`. However, I cannot properly access elements of two dimensional array.

The array is defined as:

```
double[][] sales = new double[ 5 ][ 4 ]
```

but when I try to do this:

```
sales[ product - 1 ][ person - 1 ] += amount;
```

... it doesn't save increment the sales amount. I think I am violating the index of the array.

Here is the entire code block:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sales2
{
   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
      // sales array holds data on number of each product sold
      // by each salesperson
      double[][] sales = new double[ 5 ][ 4 ]; // 5 salespeople, 
                                               //4 products each person

      System.out.print( "Enter salesperson number (-1 to end): " );
      int person = input.nextInt(); // the salesperson index

      while (person != -1)
      {
      System.out.print( "Enter product number: " );
      int product = input.nextInt(); // the product index
       // prompt user to enter product number and save it as an integer
      System.out.print( "Enter sales amount: " );
      double sales = input.nextInt();
    // promp to enter sales amont and save it as double

      sales[ product - 1 ][ person - 1 ] += amount;
         // Having trouble with the following.  I tried to manipulate
                 // the above array but nothing will work.  thanks
                 // error-check the input number for the array boundary
         // that is the person index should be 0 - 3
         // and the product index should be 0 - 4
         // notice that array index start with 0  
         // save the input to the sales 
                //array like sales[ product - 1 ][ person - 1 ] += amount;
         // or print message for the out of boundary input 


         System.out.print( "Enter salesperson number (-1 to end): " );
         person = input.nextInt(); // input for next sales person
      } // end while


      // total for each salesperson
      double[] salesPersonTotal = new double[ 4 ];

      // display the table      
      for ( int column = 0; column < 4; column++ )
         salesPersonTotal[ column ] = 0;  // Initialize the array

      System.out.printf( "%8s%14s%14s%14s%14s%10s\n",
            "Product", "Salesperson 1", "Salesperson 2",
            "Salesperson 3", "Salesperson 4", "Total" );

      // To do -
      // for each column of each row, print the appropriate
      // value representing a person's sales of a product
      // and calculate and print out the total for each product


      System.out.printf( "%25s","1", "2", "3",
            "4", "5" );

      // To do -
      // print out for each sales person total
          // I have been messing with these numbers but
            //it doesnt seem to be working.
   } // end main
} // end class Sales2
```

Comment: You might want to make this an actual question.

Comment: @weltraumpirat what do you mean?

Comment: You never asked one.  Just posting your assignment and waiting for others to solve it won't do any good for you or anyone else.  If you have a problem understanding arrays, then ask about how to access values in two-dimensional arrays, or if you want to value-check user input, ask about that - either way, making this an actual question will help others to solve your specific problem, and it will also enable other users to find an answer to their own question, if it is related.

Comment: I've edited this "question" but you need to make explicit exactly (1) exactly what behavior you expect to see and (2) exactly what behavior you are seeing that you don't want. We can't guess. Stackoverflow questions need to be sharp and focused on a single particular and ***well described*** problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, my Java is extremely rusty (I just drove by to edit) but even I can see that:

You use the symbol `sales` here:

```
double[][] sales = new double[ 5 ][ 4 ];
```

... but then you use the exact same symbol here:

```
double sales = input.nextInt();
```

... which is bad practice in any language. It will confuse humans even if not the VM.

I suspect your problem with this line:

```
sales[ product - 1 ][ person - 1 ] += amount;
```

... is that, even if the VM does figure out which of the two `sales` you intended, well, you never defined the symbol `amount` to mean anything. I think what you wanted was actually:

```
  double amount = input.nextInt();
  sales[ product - 1 ][ person - 1 ] += amount;
```

This kind of thing is easy to miss if you look at the same code over and over again. You begin to see what you intended to type as well as the associated logic instead of what the code actually reads. Everybody does it, even old hands.

Answer (score 0):

If you worry about the violating the index, you can try to use Map to store your date. Such as:

```
Map<Integer,Map<Integer,Integer>> saleMap= new HashMap<Integer,Map<Integer,Integer>>;
Map<Integer,Integer> productMountMap = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>;
productMountMap.put(product,mount);
//.. add more proudct mount map as you like. you don't need worry about the violate index
saleMap.put(person,productMountMap);

//Get one person's data using "person" as the key.
Map<Integer,Integer> b = saleMap.get(person) // so you get the product mount map.
```

Comment: thanks .....i think its ok to not worry about the volatile index in this case.  is there a way to just define a new array to handle it.  i tried doing that with sales[ product - 1 ][ person - 1 ] += amount; but that is not right

Comment: So you can try the Map<key,value> data structure. The internal implement of the map is also Array.  As the array must be static size, or you can inspect the index every time you insert a value and if the violate, just new a new array, copy old data , insert new data. That is the way List<T> does.

Comment: well, i created imports for map and hash map with the above code but am getting compile errors.